# What's a "prototypical reference class"?

Tags: r, class

The R source code mentions "prototypical reference classes" in a few places.

- [`refClass.R`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e5b21d0397c607883ff25cca379687b86933d730/src/library/methods/R/refClass.R#L391)
- [`str.R`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/32626bff9339c3a47cea89843429c8a6157c1f34/src/library/utils/R/str.R#L231)
- [`all.equal.R`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/8f58f2542cd6f8387c5eee6a77d1cd4c9aece9f8/src/library/base/R/all.equal.R#L168)

The `?ReferenceClasses` help page doesn't mention "prototypes" anywhere.

What are these prototypical reference classes?

(I know I'm not supposed to ask for off-site resources, but links to documentation would be useful.)